# Exact number of events to get the expected outcoms

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose in a competition 11 matches are to be played, each having one of 3
distinct outcomes as possibilities. How many number of ways one can predict the
outcomes of all 11 matches such that exactly 6 of the predictions turn out to
be correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  $6$ matches on which our prediction is correct can be chosen in $\binom{11}{6}$ ways. For each of these choices, we can make wrong predictions on the remaining $5$ matches in $2^5$ ways. Thus the total number is
$$\binom{11}{6}2^5.$$

Answer (score 3):

11 choose 6 ways to select the matches that are correctly predicted. Each of these have to be correct, so you can't sub-choose the outcome (win/loss/draw). But for each of the wrong predictions, you have 2 ways of being wrong. So 2 to the 5 times 11 choose 6.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You have $11$ match guesses, out of which $6$ of the guesses are exactly right. So, probability of any random $6$ is $1$, so probability of predicting other $5$ games will be $0$.

So, you choose any $6$ matches out of $11$ **AND** other other games' possible outcomes are wrong(which have two options left). When you have **AND**, you multiply number of ways of both.As Andre Nicolas suggested.